# Splunk - Add Conditional On Input

Tags: splunk

I have a Splunk Dashboard. This dashboard has a Text input where the user can enter a path. After entering the input, I would like to apply some conditional logic to the path input by the user *before* the search is executed. Is this possible in Splunk? Is there a way for me to take the Text input (i.e. path) and do something like:

```
var parameter1 = "value-a";
if (path == "/endpoint-1")
  parameter1 = "value-b";
else if (path == "/endpoint-2")
  parameter1 = "/endpoint-3";

// Execute search with parameter1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subsearches!
Eg:

```
index=data [
| makeresults 1
| eval path="$inputToken$"
| eval parameter1=case(
path="/endpoint-1","value-b,
path="/endpoint-2","/endpoint-3")
| fields parameter1
| format]
```

the subsearches are run before the main search, and alter that main search.
the main search here after the subsearch would be something like.

```
index=data parameter1="value-b"
```

Related reading to help on your sub search journey

> https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchTutorial/Useasubsearch
>
> https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Format
>
> https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Return